# What P02 abbreviation in SAP P02 means?

Tags: sap

I'm new in the SAP world. Sorry, I believe the question can be obvious, but I couldn't find on the Internet what the **P02** abbreviation in "SAP P02" means?

Comment: I'd assume its Production node 2, but who knows.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is really some of my new company's internal terms/conventions.

Comment: I guess more context would be needed to answer that question. Most likely "P02" ist just a "SID" (a special name). Names and semantics do not always correlate, however.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said above by Frank Thomas, P02 looks like a system ID, and if so then 'P' likely indicates it's a production system.  SAP systems such as ECC, BW, etc. are often referenced by a system ID and a client - e.g. P02 might have a client of 100 (client 100 would be the main user-facing environment, though there may be other client environments established by the administrators - e.g. client 800 might be reserved for sys admins to perform maintenance, etc.)

If P02 is your production system, then you might also have systems such as S01, D01, Q01 etc. which might indicate Sandbox, Development, Quality, etc.  These are typical abbreviations that *might* be used, though ultimately the company/customer will define their own nomenclature (as suggested by Adam Shakhabov).